# access 2003 parent/child recursive search

Tags: ms-access, recursion, vba

How do i create a parent/child relationship that VB6.5 will put into a tree like view using a recursive search.

I have a simple table structure that I'm experementing with before I begin using the main database.

```
ID   |   Part    | ParentId
-----+-----------+---------
1    | Tire      | 0
2    | Door      | 0
3    | Break     | 1
4    | Line      | 3
5    | Handle    | 2
6    | Fluid     | 4
and so on
```

Then I want to display the results in a listbox in the format of

```
ID   |   Part    | Relationship
-----+-----------+---------------------------------------------------
1    | Tire      | Tire
3    | Break     | Tire | Break
4    | Line      | Tire | Break | Line
6    | Fluid     | Tire | Break | Line | Fluid
2    | Door      | Door
5    | Handle    | Door | Handle
```

Comment: There is no such thing as VB6.5. Do you mean VBA?

Answer (score 2):

A nice (but not well formated :) solution: [Recursive Joins to Query Data Hierarchies in Microsoft Access](http://www.allbusiness.com/technology/software-services-applications/8897982-1.html)

The author also points out how this can be done in other DBMS (like Oracle).